# PowerShell Function for Adding Specific Users to Local RDP Group Remotely

Tags: windows, powershell, function

I feel like there's a simple answer to this, but I have been all over the interwebs and this site, and I can't quite figure this out.  I have created a function that will allow me to add a specific user to the local RDP group, but I'm trying to make it a little more simple by being able to add the username when running the function command (trying to add this to a script I'm building).
Anyway, here's what I have so far.  This works, but:

```
function Add-LocalRDPUser ( $svrName ) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $svrName -ScriptBlock { 
      $member = "DOMAIN\" + (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter UserName to add")
      Write-Host "[ Adding Member '$member' to the 'Remote Desktop Users' group on '$env:COMPUTERNAME' ]"
      Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $member
      Write-Host "[ Group members for Server $env:COMPUTERNAME =" (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Remote Desktop Users').Name " ]"
  }
}
```

This method works, but it requires two sets of inputs:

Once when I initiate the command:

```
PS C:\> Add-LocalRDPUser <RemoteServerName>
```

And once when it asks for the username input:

```
PS C:\> Add-LocalRDPUser <RemoteServerName>
Enter UserName to add: <SubjectUserName>
[ Adding Member 'DOMAIN\<SubjectUserName>' to the 'Remote Desktop Users' group on '<RemoteServerName>' ]
[ Group members for Server <RemoteServerName> = DOMAIN\<SubjectUserName> ]
PS C:\>
```

Does anyone have an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would seem to be to send both values through at once to the function. So you'd edit your script to be :

```
function Add-LocalRDPUser ( $svrName, $userName ) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $svrName -ScriptBlock { 
      param($uName)
      $member = "DOMAIN\" + $uName
      Write-Host "[ Adding Member '$member' to the 'Remote Desktop Users' group on '$env:COMPUTERNAME' ]"
      Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $member
      Write-Host "[ Group members for Server $env:COMPUTERNAME =" (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Remote Desktop Users').Name " ]"
  } -ArgumentList $userName
}
```

Then call it with :

```
PS C:\> Add-LocalRDPUser <RemoteServerName> <username>
```

(note, there's a comma between server and username in the function line, but NOT when you're calling it)

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. Main thing to remember with sending parameters like that in a function is the variable inside the scriptblock is different to outside. So inside I specify $uName via the param() line which is used within it, then outside the -ArgumentList is used to tell the scriptblock what value you're passing to $uName, in this case $userName which has been defined earlier.